# ReferenceError: Cannont find variable: Notification on iPhone devices

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, notifications, service-worker

I just want to call `notifyTest` function on button click. `notifyTest` sends notification to user in desired web browser. It is working perfectly in desktop browsers: Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Also on Android, working fine. But on iPhone devices, it doesn't work. Error is `ReferenceError: Cannont find variable: Notification`.

```
  const notifyTest = () => {
try {
  if (
    Notification.permission === 'denied' ||
    Notification.permission === 'default'
  ) {
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      console.log(permission)
      alert('permission current', permission)
      if (permission === 'granted') {
        navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then((sw) => {
          let options = {
            body: 'Its a wonderful wonderful live',
            //icon: 'img/Sukusuku Hakutaku.png',
          }
          sw.showNotification('Lets do the harlem shake', options)
        })
      }
    })
  } else {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then((sw) => {
      let options = {
        body: 'Its a wonderful wonderful live',
        //icon: 'img/Sukusuku Hakutaku.png',
      }
      sw.showNotification('Lets do the harlem shake', options)
    })
  }
} catch (error) {
  alert(error)
}
```

}

Can I achieve notification functionality of any kind on iPhone devices? Thanks in advance!